# How to get pending and failed transaction from web3?

Tags: web3js

I want my front end to show the status of my solidity functions. When my functions are successful I fire a "success" event. I can watch for that event and respond to it like so:

```
const events = myContract.allEvents({ fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest' })
      events.watch( (err, evt) => {}
```

However, I would also like to display when these functions are pending and when they have failed, but I cant figure out how.

I notice that when I do this:

```
await web3.eth.filter("pending").watch(
      function(error,result){
          if (!error) {
              console.log("pending" + result);
          }
      }
    )
```

I can see various transactions as they are pending, but I'm not sure how to tell if one of them corresponds to one of the functions I care about.

I'm not even sure how I would figure out if a transaction has failed.

Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can see various transactions as they are pending, but I'm not sure
>   how to tell if one of them corresponds to one of the functions I care
>   about.

After you make a transaction, web3 gives you a transaction hash. This uniquely identifies the transaction.

> I'm not even sure how I would figure out if a transaction has failed.

You use `eth.getTransactionReceipt(transactionHash)` (after transaction is mined) and check the `status` field. A status of 1 denotes success, whereas 0 denotes failure.

Comment: The problem is that if I refresh the page then I lose the transaction hash web3 gives me. Is there a way to identify which transactions are which function without the transaction hash? Perhaps by using the method signature?

Comment: @markoland localStorage not an option?

Comment: @ReyHaynes hot really. were trying to build without dynamic hosting

Comment: @markoland Gotcha. Well, I only mentioned it because you are always going to lose data if you refresh the page without actually storing it somewhere.

Comment: I guess it will be possible to regenerate the transaction hash from the transaction fields: `to`, `nonce`, `gasPrice`, `data`, `gasLimit` and `value`, but this means you will have to retain these values instead.